# Conversion of Japanese fonts returns an error in pdf2swf

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe, pdf2swf

When i am issuing the command

```
pdf2swf japanese.pdf -o japanese.swf -f -T 9 -t -s storeallcharacters
```

conversion returns an error:

```
Error: Unknown font tag 'HGTT_0'
Error: Unknown font tag 'HGTT_1'
Error (27721): No font in show
Error: Unknown font tag 'HGTT_1'
Error (33717): No font in show
Error: Unknown font tag 'F0'
Error (38443): No font in show
Error: Unknown character collection 'Adobe-Japan1'
Error: Couldn't find '90msp-RKSJ-H' CMap file for 'Adobe-Japan1' collection
Error: Unknown CMap '90msp-RKSJ-H' for character collection 'Adobe-Japan1'
Error: Unknown font tag 'F0'
Error (244537): No font in show
```

I have checked the path file for CMAP in adobe and it shows that I have Adobe-Japan1 CMAP under C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Resource\CMAP.

Then what I tried so far is to download CMaps for PDF CJK Fonts in here

[Download CMAP for Japan](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/font/index.html)

and replaced what is under the path. I am looking everywhere for fonts 'HGTT_0, HGTT_1, F0' in the web but still no luck. I research more of the problem and found out this [Japanese Font conversion problem](http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/swftools-common/2010-10/msg00070.html), might have some information I missed? Please help me to understand, why is pdf2swf still report for a notice that It cannot find 'Adobe-Japan1' collection wherein I actually have it?

Comment: did anyone check on this?

Comment: what i've done so far is to convert the pdf's into images using imagemagick and then use jpeg2swf to convert. but is there any way to use pdf2swf?